# Is there a way to map chrome extension's `chrome.tabs` to puppeteer's browser.pages()?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, puppeteer

In extensions `chrome.tabs` returns a `tab` which has a `tab.id` as well as a `tab.windowId`. Is there any way to get the `tab.Id` for a page or `tab.windowId` in puppeteer?

I see `targetId`, `browserContextId`, and `sessionId`, neither of which are the `tab.id` I am looking for.

Comment: It's not exposed. Why do you need it?

Comment: I am trying to send an event from extension to puppeteer to run a small script. But I can't get the current page where the extension was triggered.